# How to get/set request/response header in middelware [Nest Fastify]?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

How to inject a request header in NestJS using Fastify.

```js
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify'; // fastify types are not valid

@Injectable()
export class TracingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    console.log('MyRequestHeaderKey', req.headers['MyRequestHeaderKey']); // find out how to get a header 
    res.header('MyResponseHeaderKey', 'MyResponseHeaderValue'); // find out how to set headers
    next();
  }
}
```

There is no reference for fastify middleware on nest docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

I have read fastify doc without success: https://www.fastify.io/docs/v1.13.x/Reply/
& https://www.fastify.io/docs/v1.13.x/Request/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleware with Nest is Express-style middleware. While it is possible to work with Fastify, do note that you're essentially accessing `req.raw` and `res.raw` instead of `FastifyRequest` and `FastifyReply`. [Guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) and [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) are usually more successful at working with Fastify than standard middleware are, as a heads up.

With all that said, `req.headers` should pull back the `headers` property on the [`Incoming Request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers), and [`res.setHeader()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) should be used for setting a header on the `ServerResponse`

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to include that in nest documentation.

Comment: @Jay can you provide an example?

Comment: @FooBar example of what, specifically? using a guard or interceptor? Using the `ServerResponse` type object?